# How to use the gRPC gateway with a C++ based gRPC server

Tags: grpc, reverse-proxy, api-gateway, gateway, grpc-go

I'm going through the [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway#usage) docs and I'm able to generate the reverse proxy and stubs for my C++ service and even implement the backend functionality.

My problem comes from poorly understanding how reverse proxies work and I'm unable to use the generated services. The obvious first thing is to run my gateway:

```
go run echo_service.gw.go --port=90091
```

The default should be 8080, but I'm making things explicit by using a custom port. Now say the "actual" gRPC server is running in the same host and I've exposed a command line argument to dynamically set the port it listens on:

```
my_server.exe --port=???
```

What port should I specify? All the material I can study mentions "it doesn't matter". But I cannot see how this would be possible. The client connect directly to the gateway, and the gateway is supposed to find the gRPC server.

- How can this "server discovery" happen?
- Should I tweak my gRPC server implementation to somehow connect to the gateway?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gRPC Gateway but Step 5 [Write an entrypoint](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway?tab=readme-ov-file#5-write-an-entrypoint-for-the-http-reverse-proxy-server) is the implementation of the gateway (proxy) and it takes a flag `--grpc-server-endpoint` that defaults to `localhost:9090` but should point to the port you're gRPC server is publishing. You must configure it with the port on which you're gRPC server is running; it's unable to discover the port.

Comment: @DazWilkin So the gRPC gateway doesn't just work after generating it with protoc? I'll have to study the code, not so familiar with Go. That entrypoint, that's the thing I'll end up running right? i.e. `go run entrypoint.go` should give me a running reverse gateway?

Comment: Okay, so I went through the tutorial and it works for me using Go for both the proxy and the service implementation. Assuming you've implemented the example's `your.service.v1.YourService/Echo` in C++, you should be able to use a tool such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to invoke the method on your gRPC service: `grpcurl --plaintext --import-path=${PWD}/protos --import-path=${HOME}/Projects/googleapis --proto=${PWD}/protos/your/service/v1/your_service.proto -d '{"value":"Freddie"}' localhost:50051 your.service.v1.YourService/Echo`

Comment: If that correctly echoes `{"value":"Freddie"}` then you should then be able to run the gRPC Gateway (proxy) e.g. `go run . --grpc-server-endpoint=localhost:50051` (I'm running the gRPC service on the localhost too on port `50051`). Then, you can use `curl` (because it's now HTTP/REST) to browse the service: `curl --request POST -d '{"value":"Freddie"}' http://localhost:8081/v1/example/echo` (**NB** the Proxy defaults to `8081` and it's configured to use the gRPC service on port `50051`) and this should also return `{"value":"Freddie"}`.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks that was most helpful. I was able to run `main.go` without the server part (commented everything out except for the gateway creation), run my C++ based gRPC service and verify with gRPCurl

Comment: So, you're gRPC service is good. Next step, generate Go Gateway stubs (step #4) and implement the gateway (step #5) referencing the files generated in step #4 in the `import` section. Then run the Go Gateway ensuring you connect correctly to your known-working gRPC server. Then, you should be able to use `curl` to `POST` to the Gateway.

Comment: @DazWilkin went through that already, it works for my simple service. Main pain-points were to correctly generate the stubs (quite a lot of dependencies to take care of) and tweaking the `main.go` entry-point to "dial" the actual server (the thing you mention in your very first comment). I'm logging out now, but if you want to compile your comments into an answer I'll accept it when I log in again.

Comment: I think there's no Answer I could provide. I think you mostly needed some support through using the Go gateway. I'm pleased to hear you have it working.